# How can i connect OPNsense router to Mikrotik Switch

Tags: networking, router, switch, mikrotik, opnsense

I've encountered this situation where I'm to access the switch from my router:
Here is what i have set:

- Lan (DHCP 192.168.50.1 , DHCPIPV6)
- WAN (DHCP 192.168.80.1,DHCPIPV6)
- Mikrotik (DHCP 192.168.80.1,DHCPIPV6) [connected to Mikrotik network switch]
- VLAN_Mikrotik (DHCP 192.168.81.1, DHCPIPV6)

click on [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ctRc.png) to see it

When i type 192.168.88.1 (Mikrotik Default IP) i cannot access it. Because this is my very first time to do this so it would be best that you can guide me on how to do it.

Comment: None of your interfaces have that IP address.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Can you please elaborate further

Comment: You said: "When i type 192.168.88.1 (Mikrotik Default IP) i cannot access it." But the configuration you show has no interface with that IP address.